# Additional hidden form input, causes table cell to expand on IE7 (screenshot)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

This is one of the weirdest things I've seen,
I have a form inside a table cell, which contains hidden inputs.
I've noticed that in IE7, once there are more than 1 hidden inputs, the cell expands.

Here's a screenshot (says three but also two) :

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<table border="1" class="fix">
    <col style="width:150px;" />
    <col style="width:200px;" />
    <col style="width:200px;" />
    <col style="width:200px;" />
    <col style="width:190px;" />
      <tr>
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"><form action="a.php" method="GET">
          <input name="a" type="hidden" value="1"/>
          <input name="b" type="hidden" value="2"/>
          <div class="button-zone"><input type="submit" class="button" value="ABCDEF GEHIJKLM"></div></form></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
        <td class="cell"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Once I delete the input b line (Which i need), the cell looks normal.

Here's the CSS:

```
table.fix {
     table-layout: fixed;
}

table.fix td { 
overflow: hidden;
}

td {
    padding: .31em 1em 2em 1em;
    text-align: left;
}

.cell {
    background-color: gray;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: .44em;
}

.button-zone {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    border: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 8px;
}
```

This happens on IE7, any way to fix this without modifying sizes?

Answer (score 0):

You can set CSS like this :

```
input[type="hidden"]{
    height:0;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't make any difference, sorry